# WPF WebBrowser, Answer Yes to Internet Explorer Script Error

Tags: jquery, wpf, browser, silent

A lot has been said about supressing scripts error in WebBrowser. I'm using [solution from SO by Ondrej](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9739066/725116)

The silent mode works nice but there is a problem. 
My WPF application has the access to related web application through WebBrowser. Few pages use jQuery DatePicker plugin and it doesn't work in WebBrowser. I just can't change the date. If I disable silent mode - Scrip Errors will show and if I click 'Yes' every time - DatePickers work fine.

It's not only my web application related problem - WebBrowser is not working properly with any other site where script errors occure (like some map sites, etc.).

In Internet Explorer (8) it's ok.

The question is - can I force Silent Mode to "say yes" to every script error? Or is it possible to programatically catch these errors and handle Yes answer while not being in Silent Mode?