# Assertion failed when opening Facebook eml in WPF WebBrowser

Tags: c#, wpf, browser, assertions, eml

I have some saved eml files and im displaying them in a WPF WebBrowser control by renaming the file extension to .mht, which IE (& therefore the WebBrowser control) will display quite happily.

Im having problems displaying eml files from FaceBook, I get an Assertion failed error like this in a MessageBox :-

```
Assertion failed!

Program:....bin\Debug\myApp.vshost.exe
File:../external/boost_1_31_0\boost/shared_ptr.hpp
Line: 254

Expression: px !=0
```

It completely crashes the app.

I have thousands of eml files with all sorts of content but I only get this error reading FaceBook emails (the spammy ones they auto send with every bit of activity on your FB account).

I have suppressed Script errors as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138199/wpf-webbrowser-control-how-to-supress-script-errors) StackOverflow post but the errors persist.

I have a try catch around the wb.Navigate(Uri) statements but its not caught it.

How can I stop the errors?

Answer (score 0):

OK so not one answer! I knew it was a little far out :-)

For anyone having a similar issue, I ended up scrapping the WPF WebBrowser and going with [awesomium](http://awesomium.com/) which is an open source WPF WebBrowser alternative with a LOT more power & capabilities.

All the errors disappeared and im now happy.