# Handle window.close() event in WPF browser control

Tags: wpf, webbrowser-control

**HTML of the page is**

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <title>This is Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button  value="Hello World" onclick="test()"  style="width: 171px; height: 77px"></button>
    </body>
</html>
<script>
    function test() {
        window.close();
    }
</script>
```

**WPF code is**

```
BrowserWindow1.Navigate(TextBox1.Text)
```

When I click on the button on the browser. Browser control gives me this message

**The web page you are viewing is trying to close the tab.
Do you want to close this tab?**

I want to handle this thing before prompting this message and after prompting this message and thus override the default functionality of browser control with mine functionality.

Comment: You can try that : `window.onbeforeunload` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13443503/how-to-run-javascript-code-on-window-close however I am not sure if you can change a browser built in behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Try handling [`WindowClosing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768301%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) event on the underlying `WebBrowser` ActiveX Control ([here's how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18269105/1768303) to get a hold of it with WPF version of `WebBrowser`). If that doesn't work, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19673012/1768303) one.