# How to make WebBrowser complete navigation when running in a headless unit test?

Tags: c#, wpf, nunit, webbrowser-control

We have a WPF application that loads some content in a `<WebBrowser/>` control and then makes some calls based on what was loaded.  With the right mocks, we think we can test this inside a displayless unit test (NUnit in this case).  But the `WebBrowser` control doesn't want to play nicely.

The problem is that we never receive the `LoadCompleted` or `Navigated` events.  Apparently this is because a web-page is never "Loaded" until it is actually rendered [(see this MSDN thread)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/de-DE/60ef78a0-de9b-4f5b-97f2-4de00bcf5e23/webbrowser-controls-loadcompleted-event-is-not-firing-wpf?forum=wpf). We do receive the `Navigating` event, but that comes far too early for our purposes.

So is there a way to make the `WebBrowser` control work "fully" even when it has no output to display to?

Here is a cut-down version of the test case:

```
[TestFixture, RequiresSTA]
class TestIsoView
{
    [Test] public void PageLoadsAtAll()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm a lumberjack and I'm OK");
        WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();

        // An AutoResetEvent allows us to synchronously wait for an event to occur.
        AutoResetEvent autoResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        //wb.LoadCompleted += delegate  // LoadCompleted is never received
        wb.Navigated += delegate  // Navigated is never received
        //wb.Navigating += delegate // Navigating *is* received
        {
            // We never get here unless we wait on wb.Navigating
            Console.WriteLine("The document loaded!!");
            autoResetEvent.Set();
        };

        Console.WriteLine("Registered signal handler", "Navigating");

        wb.NavigateToString("Here be dramas");
        Console.WriteLine("Asyncronous Navigations started!  Waiting for A.R.E.");
        autoResetEvent.WaitOne();
        // TEST HANGS BEFORE REACHING HERE.
        Console.WriteLine("Got it!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to spin off an STA thread with a message loop for that. You'd create an instance of `WebBrowser` on that thread and suppress script errors. Note, a WPF `WebBrowser` object needs a live host window to function. That's how it's different from WinForms `WebBrowser`.

Here is an example of how this can be done:

```
static async Task<string> RunWpfWebBrowserAsync(string url)
{
    // return the result via Task
    var resultTcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();

    // the main WPF WebBrowser driving logic
    // to be executed on an STA thread
    Action startup = async () => 
    {
        try
        {
            // create host window
            var hostWindow = new Window();
            hostWindow.ShowActivated = false;
            hostWindow.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            hostWindow.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            hostWindow.Show();

            // create a WPF WebBrowser instance
            var wb = new WebBrowser();
            hostWindow.Content = wb;

            // suppress script errors: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18289217
            // touching wb.Document makes sure the underlying ActiveX has been created
            dynamic document = wb.Document; 
            dynamic activeX = wb.GetType().InvokeMember("ActiveXInstance",
                BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
                null, wb, new object [] { });
            activeX.Silent = true;

            // navigate and handle LoadCompleted
            var navigationTcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
            wb.LoadCompleted += (s, e) => 
                navigationTcs.TrySetResult(true);
            wb.Navigate(url);
            await navigationTcs.Task;

            // do the WebBrowser automation
            document = wb.Document;
            // ...

            // return the content (for example)
            string content = document.body.outerHTML;
            resultTcs.SetResult(content);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // propogate exceptions to the caller of RunWpfWebBrowserAsync
            resultTcs.SetException(ex);
        }

        // end the tread: the message loop inside Dispatcher.Run() will exit
        Dispatcher.ExitAllFrames();
    };

    // thread procedure
    ThreadStart threadStart = () =>
    {
        // post the startup callback
        // it will be invoked when the message loop pumps
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(startup);
        // run the WPF Dispatcher message loop
        Dispatcher.Run();
        Debug.Assert(true);
    };

    // start and run the STA thread
    var thread = new Thread(threadStart);
    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    thread.Start();
    try
    {
        // use Task.ConfigureAwait(false) to avoid deadlock on a UI thread
        // if the caller does a blocking call, i.e.:
        // "RunWpfWebBrowserAsync(url).Wait()" or 
        // "RunWpfWebBrowserAsync(url).Result"
        return await resultTcs.Task.ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    finally
    {
        // make sure the thread has fully come to an end
        thread.Join();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
// blocking call
string content = RunWpfWebBrowserAsync("http://www.example.com").Result;

// async call
string content = await RunWpfWebBrowserAsync("http://www.example.org")
```

You may also try to run `threadStart` lambda directly on your `NUnit` thread, without actually creating a new thread. This way, the NUnit thread will run the `Dispatcher` message loop. I'm not familiar with NUnit well enough to predict if that works.

If you don't want to create a host window, consider using [WinForms `WebBrowser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead. I posted a similar [self-contained example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19718530/1768303) of doing that from a console app.

Comment: Thank I will try it out when I get to work.  Do you need to actually `.Show()` the host `Window`, or just insert the `Browser` into it?  Last time I called `.Show()` from inside a unit test everything exploded.

Comment: @AdrianRatnapala, you do need `.Show()` as it physically creates a Windows handle behind the scene. It will flash and hide, because of `hostWindow.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden`. I can't be sure about NUnit, but this code works for me in the console app (tested as as `Console.WriteLine(RunWpfWebBrowserAsync("http://www.example.com").Result)` from `Main`).

Comment: It works.  And yes, it flashes the window.  Annoying, but such is life.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it works, but if you are using a mocking framework like Moq, you could mock the "IsLoaded" property to being 'true' and trick the WebBrowser in being loaded.

This of course, might reveal that the WebBrowser actually needs a display to be completely functional, which wouldn't surprise me. Much of html, javascript and the dom depends on screen-measurements and -events.