# How to suppress Javascript errors in winform web browser control?

Tags: c#, javascript, wpf, winforms, browser

In my application, I am trying to suppress script errors while navigating to pages hosted in a winform `webbrowser` and I don't want to use `webBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;` property as it blocks all windows. I tried multiple approaches to resolve it including this one.

[Disable Javascript error in WPF WebBrowser control](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2010/08/31/disable-javascript-error-in-wpf-webbrowser-control/)

I am still getting script errors that too after `DocumentCompleted`event subscription. 
Has any one tried with better approach ?

Comment: Check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24988467/how-can-i-confirm-script-error-dialog-box-into-webbrowser

Comment: Thanks Jack, I was looking for something similar.

Comment: Did it solve your question?

Comment: today started implementing @office...will update you in case of any queries. thanks for asking :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I confirm script error dialog box into WebBrowser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24988467/how-can-i-confirm-script-error-dialog-box-into-webbrowser)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WebBrowser control and JavaScript errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529615/webbrowser-control-and-javascript-errors)