# Script Error in webBrowser control WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-4.0

[image]

When am work on webBrowser control using wpf Getting error like "script error" even i pasted screen shot here and even some jquery UI and css not working

Comment: We'll need more information on this one.

Comment: Xaml:<Grid>
      <WebBrowser HorizontalAlignment="Left"
      Height="400"   Height="800"
      VerticalAlignment="Top"
       Name="Browserurl"/>
   </Grid>

Comment: Had you tried my solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF WebBrowser control - how to supress script errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138199/wpf-webbrowser-control-how-to-supress-script-errors)

Answer (score 2):

I faced this problem too. I need to create browser application which the web has lot of Jquery, JSON etc and webbrowser control does't work as expected (I'm using Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2015)

As solution, I use [cefsharp.github.io](http://cefsharp.github.io) which allow me to embed a full-featured standards-complaint web browser into C# or VB.NET project solution without hacking windows registry key. It based on Chromium Embedded Framework. It work like a charm!

[image]
Just grab nuget packages and create ChromiumWebBrowser class and you are ready to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your WebBrowser rendering engine, by default it uses the oldest one.

In this link Microsoft describes how you can do it:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ee330730%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

And you can follow this good answer too.
[Will the IE9 WebBrowser Control Support all of IE9's features, including SVG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612255/regarding-ie9-webbrowser-control/5357168#5357168)

**Pay attention that if you are running a 32 bit app on a 64bit system you must set this key instead**

```
[HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION]
```

I tried the site that fails in your screenshot and works well with this registry change from a WebBrowser.