# Spotify authorization code flow (WPF browser control) C#

Tags: c#, wpf, oauth-2.0, spotify, spotify-desktop

I'm using Spotify account service (authorization code flow) to get an authorization code by passing in the required parameters (client_id, response_type and redirect_uri. Its a WPF application so i am using the browser control and navigating the user to

```
https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize/?client_id=myclientId&response_type=code&redirect_uri=someUri
```

When i copy paste the link in the browser, i see the right stuff i.e page with the Login to Spotify button but when i am navigating through the browser control in my WPF application, it gives me a file download dialog with Authorize.json file to download with Open and Save options, however in some cases it presents the right page to browser code.

Below is my code:

```
    public winOAuthBrowserForm(string navigateTo)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        webBrowser.Navigated += webBrowser_Navigated;
        webBrowser.Navigate(navigateTo);

    }


    private void webBrowser_Navigated(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Uri.Query))
        {
            //since we are looking for code for authorization that will be exchanged for request token from the server
            if (e.Uri.Query.StartsWith("?code=") || e.Uri.Query.Contains("code="))
            {
                code = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(e.Uri.Query).Get("code");
                this.Close();
            }

            if (e.Uri.Query.StartsWith("?error=") || e.Uri.Query.Contains("error="))
            {
                error = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(e.Uri.Query).Get("error");
                this.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

And i am calling this control like:

```
            var uri = string.Format(SpotifyAuthUriFormatter, RequestAuthBaseUrl, clientId);
            winOAuthBrowserForm form = new winOAuthBrowserForm(uri);
            form.ShowDialog();
```

This is what i see:

[image]

UPDATE: When i right click on document and see the properties, i see it changes the URL to something like res://ieframe.dll/navcancl.htm#... I've searched it and found some solutions related to I.E (I'm using latest but you can't be sure that it'll be latest on client machines), some say that its firewall setting. The thing is, it appears sometimes only.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: The first thing that i suggest when working with WebBrowser under Wpf is this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32332206/script-error-in-webbrowser-control-wpf/32353967#32353967

If it will work we can update this to an answer to your question ;-)

Comment: I've tried setting the registry keys for both 32 and 64bit machines as you have stated in your answer on the link.  I've set the DWORD as hexadecimal 2af9 which is 11001 but it presents the same file download dialog. It keeps redirecting me to res://ieframe.dll/navcancl.htm