# WebBrowser not loading youtube tv

Tags: c#, wpf, youtube

i have the following URL that doesnt behave in the WPF WebBrowser control as expected. It basically loads only a youtube background image and then stops .. where as firefox/chrome etc. load the youtube view you get on tv-apps.

is there a way to make the WebBrowser load this in the same way?

https://www.youtube.com/tv#/browse-sets?c=UCZGYJFUizSax-yElQaFDp5Q&resume

i tried to parse the same page downloaded with a webclient.. but its also only loading an background page and i dont know how to continue from here.

thanks in advance for any hints

Answer (score 1):

Wpf WebBrowser is a wrapper for IE. If you try to open the link you provided with IE (11 in my case) you can see that it won't work (not supported).

If you change the version of IE that your WebBrowser use (as i described here [Script Error in webBrowser control WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32332206/script-error-in-webbrowser-control-wpf/32353967#32353967)) you can see the not supported page.

You can try using something like https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/ or https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp

Comment: Thats interesting .. for me both IE 11 as well as Edge (Windows 10) do load the page just in the same way FF or Chrome do, without any problems. So there must still be something else different in your case. 

I will check out your links .. never heard of either of these before.
thanks already

Comment: IE 11 on win7 doesn't work for me, however try with registry method.

Comment: Add you tried to change the registry key as described in my post to make it work?

Comment: i didnt try much with the registry as it would be a no-go for me to meddle with such entries on the computers of my users. 

but i will be exploring about the other two links that you posted as i guess those would give better solution to the problem.. i just will need to try a bit about which of the two i will be more comfortable with.

Comment: Ok, we went in a similar case inserting the key in the registry from setup (launched as administrator). However you can reach the same results with GeckoFx or CefSharp. Good work.