# Embedding Youtube Videos in webbrowser. Object doesn't support property or method

Tags: c#, wpf, youtube

Youtube has recently stopped supporting videos embedded in the format www.youtube.com/v/{key}. So I was trying to convert the video from "/v/" to "/embed/". However when I try to navigate to the video the following errors then pop up:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am navigating to the webpage using the following:

WPF

```
<WebBrowser x:Name="trailer" Margin="655,308,30,135"/>
```

c#

```
trailer.Navigate("https://www.youtube.com/embed/v2fDTOdWuQQ?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0");
```

Why is this unable to work simply by switching from "/v/" to "/embed/"? And how do I go about resolving this issue?

Comment: Just call that before you navigate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34267121/403671

Comment: @SimonMourier I have the exact same issue and it appears that RooiWillie's answer on your link works for my situation.

Comment: @JohnOdom  yep, this is the best answer in that thread, but, hey, it's not worth 500 bucks :-)

Comment: See [blog example](https://sachingpta.gitlab.io/_posts/youtube.html), you may use `<iframe width="100%" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/0mNptklwylc?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>` to embed. Its working in example page also.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is duplicate of an existing SO Thread

[Use latest version of Internet Explorer in the webbrowser control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922308/use-latest-version-of-internet-explorer-in-the-webbrowser-control)

The thread has lots of answers in it with actual code to go with it.

The best suggestion in the same is to set a very high number of for your `app.exe` in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION`

I set it to `20000`, which is safe to assume to work in a lot of coming version and to use the latest version as such. This case is easily done during the setup of your exe as such. So you won't have to worry about which version exists and which doesn't. The minimum version you need for embedding to work is IE 9.

Also, another option is not to use Embedded IE at all. Instead, use Chromium. There is a CefSharp project for the same on

https://cefsharp.github.io/

This project allows you to embed chromium browser in your WinForms or WPF app. The app is quite simple

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using CefSharp;
using CefSharp.WinForms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        ChromiumWebBrowser chrome;

        private void InitChrome()
        {
            CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
            Cef.Initialize(settings);
            chrome = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://www.youtube.com/embed/v2fDTOdWuQQ?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0");
            this.Controls.Add(chrome);
            chrome.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        }
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitChrome();
            //this.webBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.youtube.com/embed/v2fDTOdWuQQ?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0");
        }

    }
}
```

And works great. This will make your app not be dependent on which browser is installed on the target machine.

[image: Youtube Chromium]

Answer (score 1):

Use **WebBrowser.NavigateToString** instead of **WebBrowser.Navigate** and use the **HTML** instead of URL.
check this screenshot for your easy reference

[image]

Comment: You can download full working code from below link 

https://www.dropbox.com/s/peuep22qqy200ot/YoutubeIssue.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

WPF have a feature "Browser Emulation" to solve this type of issue.

Add the below enumaration

```
public enum BrowserEmulationVersion
{
    Default = 0,
    Version7 = 7000,
    Version8 = 8000,
    Version8Standards = 8888,
    Version9 = 9000,
    Version9Standards = 9999,
    Version10 = 10000,
    Version10Standards = 10001,
    Version11 = 11000,
    Version11Edge = 11001
}
```

Create a new class "InternetExplorerBrowserEmulation" and add the below codes in it.

```
public class InternetExplorerBrowserEmulation
{
    private const string InternetExplorerRootKey = @"Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer";
    private const string BrowserEmulationKey = InternetExplorerRootKey + @"\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION";


    public static int GetInternetExplorerMajorVersion()
    {
        int result;

        result = 0;

        try
        {
            RegistryKey key;

            key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(InternetExplorerRootKey);

            if (key != null)
            {
                object value;

                value = key.GetValue("svcVersion", null) ?? key.GetValue("Version", null);

                if (value != null)
                {
                    string version;
                    int separator;

                    version = value.ToString();
                    separator = version.IndexOf('.');
                    if (separator != -1)
                    {
                        int.TryParse(version.Substring(0, separator), out result);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (SecurityException)
        {
            // The user does not have the permissions required to read from the registry key.
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            // The user does not have the necessary registry rights.
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static bool SetBrowserEmulationVersion(BrowserEmulationVersion browserEmulationVersion)
    {
        bool result;

        result = false;

        try
        {
            RegistryKey key;

            key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(BrowserEmulationKey, true);

            if (key != null)
            {
                string programName;

                programName = Path.GetFileName(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]);

                if (browserEmulationVersion != BrowserEmulationVersion.Default)
                {
                    // if it's a valid value, update or create the value
                    key.SetValue(programName, (int)browserEmulationVersion, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
                }
                else
                {
                    // otherwise, remove the existing value
                    key.DeleteValue(programName, false);
                }

                result = true;
            }
        }
        catch (SecurityException)
        {
            // The user does not have the permissions required to read from the registry key.
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            // The user does not have the necessary registry rights.
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static bool SetBrowserEmulationVersion()
    {
        int ieVersion;
        BrowserEmulationVersion emulationCode;

        ieVersion = GetInternetExplorerMajorVersion();

        if (ieVersion >= 11)
        {
            emulationCode = BrowserEmulationVersion.Version11;
        }
        else
        {
            switch (ieVersion)
            {
                case 10:
                    emulationCode = BrowserEmulationVersion.Version10;
                    break;
                case 9:
                    emulationCode = BrowserEmulationVersion.Version9;
                    break;
                case 8:
                    emulationCode = BrowserEmulationVersion.Version8;
                    break;
                default:
                    emulationCode = BrowserEmulationVersion.Version7;
                    break;
            }
        }

        return SetBrowserEmulationVersion(emulationCode);
    }

    public static BrowserEmulationVersion GetBrowserEmulationVersion()
    {
        BrowserEmulationVersion result;

        result = BrowserEmulationVersion.Default;

        try
        {
            RegistryKey key;

            key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(BrowserEmulationKey, true);
            if (key != null)
            {
                string programName;
                object value;

                programName = Path.GetFileName(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]);
                value = key.GetValue(programName, null);

                if (value != null)
                {
                    result = (BrowserEmulationVersion)Convert.ToInt32(value);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (SecurityException)
        {
            // The user does not have the permissions required to read from the registry key.
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            // The user does not have the necessary registry rights.
        }

        return result;
    }


    public static bool IsBrowserEmulationSet()
    {
        return GetBrowserEmulationVersion() != BrowserEmulationVersion.Default;
    }
}
```

Before setting URL, we need to add the below codes.

```
if (!InternetExplorerBrowserEmulation.IsBrowserEmulationSet())
{
  InternetExplorerBrowserEmulation.SetBrowserEmulationVersion();
}
```

This will run the you tube videos using the webbrowser control in WPF

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your WebBrowser to a "silent mode" (ignoring these script errors).
It requires some black IE/COM magic, but it works.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6198700/3629903 on how to do it.

Comment: Silent mode just ignores the errors and i'm left with a black box.