# VBA doesn't read XMLHTTP request's response according to its tree structure

Tags: vba, xmlhttprequest

I have checked that both browser-generated page and VBA XMLHTTP request's string response have the same tree structure, with **a** tag being a child of **aside**.

Unfortunately when I want to return bookie name, which is title attribute of **a**, I get an error accessing 1st child of **aside**. It comes out that I need to use code assuming that **a** tag is a sibling of **aside** to get it working:

[image]

Required reference: Microsoft HTML Library

```
Sub SendRequest()

Dim XMLHTTP As Object: Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
Dim htmlEle1 As IHTMLElement
Dim htmlDoc As New HTMLDocument   
Dim urlName As String

urlName = "https://www.oddschecker.com/golf/the-masters/2018-us-masters/winner"

With XMLHTTP

    .Open "GET", urlName, False
    .send
    htmlDoc.body.innerHTML = .responseText

    For Each htmlEle1 In htmlDoc.getElementsByClassName("eventTableHeader")(0).Children
        If InStr(htmlEle1.className, "bookie-area") <> 0 Then
           Debug.Print htmlEle1.Children(1).getAttribute("title")
        End If
    Next htmlEle1

End With

End Sub
```

Does this behavior have something to do with the fact that **aside** is HTML5 element and VBA thinks that it is a semi-closing tag?

Comment: Instead of `htmlDoc.body.innerHTML = .responseText` try `htmlDoc.clear()` and then `htmlDoc.write(.responseText)`

Comment: It's not possible to use HtmlDoc.write - "Compile error: Function or interface marked as restricted, or the function uses an Automation type not supported in Visual Basic"

Comment: Can you cast the document into another another object with `IHTMLDocument2` interface?

Answer (score 3):

So this took awful lot of time to figure out. The issue is that you can't do it this way. When you launch a new `HTMLDocument` the `documentMode` of it is by default set to `5`

So when we load a write any HTML inside it, it has no idea of these HTML5 tags and it just does its own correction. This is as good as you running HTML5 site in a IE6 browser or something. <s>Unfortunately there is no way I could find out which would allow us to create/parse document with a higher documentMode</s>

**Update**

Thanks to @FlorentB for pointing out that emulation mode works on the MSHTML library as well. I was already aware of the same from below

[Embedding Youtube Videos in webbrowser. Object doesn't support property or method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46185600/embedding-youtube-videos-in-webbrowser-object-doesnt-support-property-or-metho/47070779#47070779)

But I assumed it won't work for the MSHTML library. I have now tested it by running below command

```
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION" /v excel.exe /t REG_DWORD /d 11001 /f
```

And then the existing code and it works.

**Alternat approach**

If setting the registry key needs to be avoided for any reason then one can use the IE COM Browser directly.

You can do this by adding a reference to `Microsoft Internet Controls` and then execute the below code

```
Sub dothis()
Dim XMLHTTP As Object: Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
Dim htmlEle1 As IHTMLElement
Dim htmlDoc As HTMLDocument
'Set htmlIDoc = htmlDoc

Dim urlName As String

urlName = "https://www.oddschecker.com/golf/the-masters/2018-us-masters/winner"

Dim ie As InternetExplorerMedium

Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium

ie.Visible = False
ie.navigate2 urlName

While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE

    DoEvents
Wend

Set htmlDoc = ie.document

Debug.Print (htmlDoc.documentMode)
For Each htmlEle1 In htmlDoc.getElementsByClassName("eventTableHeader")(0).Children
    If InStr(htmlEle1.className, "bookie-area") <> 0 Then
       Debug.Print htmlEle1.Children(0).children(0).getAttribute("title")
    End If
Next htmlEle1

End Sub
```

And now you can see that `a` is a child of `aside`

[image: HTML5 Parsing]

Comment: execute `REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION" /v excel.exe /t REG_DWORD /d 11001 /f` and restart excel to set the document mode to IE11 for `New HTMLDocument`

Comment: Thanks @FlorentB., I am aware of the emulation settings for the IE Browser, never thought it would work for the MSHTML library also the same way. Thanks for pointing this out. I have tested it and it works great

Comment: Try adding the site to Trusted sites in IE settings and see if it helps, which IE version you have on your system?

Comment: Then both approaches should work, I had tested on Windows 7 + IE 11