# VBA HTML Object library not supporting all HTML tags

Tags: html, excel, vba

When using VBA to parse HTML in a cell row, some tags like  give problems.

For example, if I have the following content in a excel cell:

`<div><section>hello</section></div>`

And I then apply the following function

```
Public Function mainclean(sourceText As String) As String

Dim DOC As New HTMLDocument
DOC.body.innerHTML = sourceText

mainclean = DOC.body.innerHTML
End Function
```

What I get is the following:

```
<DIV>hello</SECTION></DIV>
```

The beginning of the section tag is being stripped.
Clearly the tag section is not being recognised as HTML code.

The same happens with non-html tags like `<mycustomtag></mycustomtag>`

Does it exist any workaround?

Thanks

Comment: maybe because you are declaring `sourceText` as a string.  You declared `DOC` as HTMLDocument but then you turn it into a string with `DOC.body.innerHTML = sourceText`.  Just a guess though.

Comment: I don't think `HTMLDocument` implements the latest version of IE - you may find that recent/HTML5 tags are not supported.

Comment: If you want the innertext of the html, change `innerHTML` against `innerText`. Your html code is in Excel cells because? I've never heard that's necessary.

Comment: @Zwenn - good catch  - I missed that entirely...

Comment: @TimWilliams First I had also overlooked it and written something completely different. String in, String out had distracted me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `HTMLDocument` the default `documentMode` is IE5, which means it will have some problems with recent/HTML5 tags.

If required you can get around this by using `CreateObject("htmlfile")` which creates the same type of object, but its behaviour seems to be slightly different.

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim testHTML As String
    testHTML = "<div><section>hello</section></div>"

    Debug.Print mainclean(testHTML)

    Debug.Print mainclean2(testHTML)

End Sub

Public Function mainclean2(sourceText As String) As String
    Dim DOC 'As New HTMLDocument
    Set DOC = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    Debug.Print TypeName(DOC) '>>HTMLDocument
    Debug.Print "htmlfile Default doc mode", DOC.documentMode  '>>5
    DOC.Open "text/html"
    'next line switches document mode to 8 but commenting it out
    '  still gives the "correct" output with docMode 5 (??)
    DOC.write "<head><meta http-equiv=""X-UA-Compatible"" content=""IE=Edge""></head>"
    DOC.write "<body>" & sourceText & "</body>"
    DOC.Close
    Debug.Print "Fixed doc mode", DOC.documentMode '>>8
    mainclean2 = DOC.body.innerHTML                '>>  <DIV><SECTION>hello</SECTION></DIV>
End Function

Public Function mainclean(sourceText As String) As String
    Dim DOC As New HTMLDocument
    Debug.Print TypeName(DOC)                       '>>HTMLDocument
    Debug.Print "HTMLDocument Default doc mode", _
                               DOC.documentMode     '>> 5
    DOC.body.innerHTML = sourceText
    mainclean = DOC.body.innerHTML                  '>> <DIV>hello</SECTION></DIV>
End Function
```

Related:
[VBA doesn't read XMLHTTP request's response according to its tree structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49501406/vba-doesnt-read-xmlhttp-requests-response-according-to-its-tree-structure)